# calculating the average grade give name error

Tags: python

Output should be as follows:

Give a course grade (-1 exits): 5

Give a course grade (-1 exits): 3

Give a course grade (-1 exits): 1

Give a course grade (-1 exits): 0

Grades must be between 1 and 5 (-1 exits)

Give a course grade (-1 exits): 4

Give a course grade (-1 exits): -1

Average of course grades is: 3.2

```
for x in range(0,5):
    for num in range(0,n+1,1):
        sum = sum+num
        average = sum / 5
    sub1=int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    sub2=int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    sub3=int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    sub4=int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    sub5=int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    if x>5:
        print("Grades must be between 1 and 5 (-1 exits)")
    elif x<1:
        print("Average of course grades is: ", num)
```

The code doesnt work

Comment: Edit question to show the full traceback.

Comment: Please explain `the code doesn't work`, Does it give any error or bad result, in case of bad result what does it produce?

Answer (score 1):

Give the code below a try (feel free to ask questions)

```
values = []
while True:
    value = int(input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): "))
    if value == -1:
        break
    if value < 1 or value > 5:
        print("Grades must be between 1 and 5 (-1 exits)")
        continue
    values.append(value)
if values:
    print('Avg is {}'.format(sum(values) / len(values)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name error problem comes from the line

```py
for num in range(0,n+1,1):
```

Because n is just undefined. 
But I don't think your are going through the good way with your script.
If you want to keep 5 input values maximum, you can do as following:

```py
my_inputs = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    my_input = int(
        input("Give a course grade (-1 exits): ")
    )

    if my_input == -1:
        break

    if my_input < 1 or my_input > 5:
        print("Grades must be between 1 and 5 (-1 exits)")
        continue

    my_inputs.append(my_input)

if my_inputs:
    average = sum(my_inputs) / len(my_inputs)
    print(f'Avg is {average}')
```